# WinRT DoubleAnimation to Canvas.Left

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

Quick question for the pros. I have a userControl sitting in the centre of my page. When the page is tapped I want to use a doubleAnimation to dock the control to the left of the page.

This line To="{Binding Canvas.Left}" is not working. I have to specify a value. eg. -200 which will animate (TranslateX) to the left but for some screens it never reaches the left of the page. How should I handle this? Also is the tapped event of the page the correct place to check for the first interaction on the page since it should only happen the first time the user interacts?

In my code behind I want to use something like if(usercontrol.left > 0){storyboard.begin;}. What is the best way to achieve this?

I will probably have to put a From={Binding UserControl.CurrentPosition} as well

Thanks

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="EntryAnimation">
      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                       To="{Binding Canvas.Left}" 
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                       Storyboard.TargetName="idcMain"
                       d:IsOptimized="True" />
    </Storyboard>
  </Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using storyboards, You can use system transitions (RepositionTransition in your case). This way, You Just modify the Canvas.Left property and it's automagically animated using transitions timing consistent with the global OS UX.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to apply this? Thanks

Comment: RepositionThemeTransition? Found it thanks. Will let you know if it works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.repositionthemetransition